# How can I show that $G/[A,B]$ is an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is a group such that $G=AB$, where both $A$ and $B$ are abelian.

We denote $G':=\langle[g,h]\;:\;g,h\in G\rangle=[G,G]$ and similarly $[K,H]:=\langle[k,h]\;:\;k\in K,\;h\in H\rangle$ for $H, K$ subgroups of $G$.

I need to show that $G'=[A,B]$.

$\bullet$ "$\supseteq$" is clear since $[A,B]\subseteq[AB,AB]=[G,G]=G'$

The problem is indeed the opposite inclusion: "$\subseteq$".

But one can easily show that

1) For every $H,K\le G$, we have that $[H,K]\unlhd\langle H,K\rangle$.

2) Given $N\unlhd G$ we have that $G'\le N\Longleftrightarrow\ G/N$ is abelian.

So by 1) I have that $[A,B]\unlhd\langle A,B\rangle=G$ and by 2) I have that $G'\leq[A,B]$ (that is exactly the inclusion I search) iff $G/[A,B]$ is abelian.

But I can't show that this last group is abelian. I have no idea, I've tried this only directly.

Can someone help me, please? Thank you all.

Comment: Hey, could you clarify for me when you write $AB$, do you mean the direct product of groups?  Then what is meant by $[A,B]$?

Comment: $AB$ is simply the group generated by all elements $ab$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. $[A,B]$ is defined at the beginning of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done the difficult part. Now simply note that modulo $[A, B]$ you have, for $a_{1}, a_{2} \in A$ and $b_{1}, b_{2} \in B$,
$$
(a_{1} b_{1}) (a_{2} b_{2}) \equiv a_{1} a_{2} b_{1} b_{2} \equiv a_{2} a_{1} b_{2} b_{1} \equiv (a_{2} b_{2}) (a_{1} b_{1}),
$$
since $b_{1} a_{2} \equiv a_{2} b_{1} \pmod{[A, B]}$, and $A$ and $B$ are abelian.

I write $x \equiv y \pmod{N}$, where $N$ is a normal subgroup, to mean that $x N = y N$.

Comment: thank you so much! It's clear I'm tired. :-(

Comment: You're very welcome. There is also a direct approach, expanding $[a_{1} b_{1}, a_{2} b_{2}]$, using your fact (1) in the form $[a, b]^{a'} = [a a', b] [a', b]^{-1}$, for $a, a' \in A$, and $b \in B$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof goes as follows. We have $[A,B]\triangleleft A$ and  $[A,B]\triangleleft B$, hence $[A,B]\triangleleft AB=G$. Furthermore in the group $G/[A,B]$ the images of $A$ and $B$ are abelian subgroups that centralise each other. It follows that $G/[A,B]$  is abelian, and hence that $G'\subseteq [A,B]$.

Remark: By Ito's theorem $G'$ is abelian.